# Error scraping aspx site with ruby Mechanize. Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to scrape a ratings website with Ruby's mechanize, and am having a world of trouble.  My code is pretty simple:

```
require "mechanize"
@client.get("http://cape.ucsd.edu/responses/Results.aspx")
```

At that point, you'll see the 404 errors.

I've tried a few things, including HTTParty searching for redirects; disabling SSL checking; even saving the html file locally (to get the proper query form), and then trying to issue it directly from an agent connected to the main site. All of these lead to the same error.

I'm fairly new to scraping, and I'm hoping I'm doing something silly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that it works if you point the URL somewhere else? If so I suspect user agent..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your sample code isn't correct and returns an error. It's really important that you take the time to make sure your question's code is usable by us to test. Don't expect us to rewrite it just to help solve the problem as that can result in wildly varying help. You want us to help you, so provide us what is required. If you are getting a 404 it's because your URL is wrong or the resource is no longer available. You'll need to determine the right URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's user agent. To set the user agent do:

```
@client = Mechanize.new
@client.user_agent = 'Mozilla'
```